# Animate UIView's frame and corner radius together

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

So I am trying to make a shrinking/growing circle with a UIView. I am using UIView.animateWithDuration... (blah blah blah) for the frame of the view and CABasicAnimation to animate the view's (layer's) corner radius. Both animate for the correct duration and *end* at the correct, circular values (corner radius = 1/2 width). The issue is that during the animation, CABasicAnimation and UIView.animateWithDuration seem to have different animation curves. How can I achieve a proper circle-size animation.

If the answer is to use CABAsicAnimation for the farm swell, please explain *how* to do that.

Thanks!

---

### Code:

This code is in an extension for UIView.

```
//This is how it's being used to shrink the circle:

circleview.growByPixles(-10, seconds: 0.3, completion: {})
circleview.setCornerRadius(radius:(circleview.bounds.size.width - 10) / 2 seconds: 0.3)

//////

func morphToFrame(frame: CGRect, seconds: Double, completion: () -> ()) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(seconds,
        animations: {
            self.frame = frame
        },
        completion: { _ in
            completion()
        })
}

//negative integers shrink
func growByPixels(pixels: CGFloat, seconds: Double, completion: () -> ()) {
    var f:CGRect = self.frame

    var newFrame:CGRect = CGRect(x: f.origin.x - pixels/2, y: f.origin.y - pixels/2,  width: f.size.width + pixels, height: f.size.height + pixels)

    self.morphToFrame(newFrame, seconds: seconds, completion: completion)
}

func setCornerRadius(radius: CGFloat, seconds: Double) {

    self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: Float(self.layer.cornerRadius))
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    animation.duration = seconds
    self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
}
```

Comment: I added code, theses are the three functions that are used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521554/creating-an-expanding-circle-ios/26521755#26521755 you'll need to convert it to Swift

Answer (score 6):

I resizing my circle views like this:

```
- (void)resizeCircleView:(CGRect)frame {

    CGRect estimateFrame = frame;
    float duration = 1.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [circle setFrame:estimateFrame];
    } completion:nil];

    CGFloat estimateCorner = estimateFrame.size.width / 2;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.fromValue = @(circle.layer.cornerRadius);
    animation.toValue = @(estimateCorner);
    animation.duration = duration;
    [circle.layer setCornerRadius:estimateCorner];
    [circle.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
}
```

Comment: The animations just don't working in the same moment.

Comment: Yeah, these method doesn't sync both animations