# How to transform only the button edge of a view with animation

Tags: swift, animation

I am trying to achieve an effect that when I swipe up on a view, the buttom edge will move towards the top until it disappears (the views height will become smaller and smaller).
I want the top edge to stay in place and only the buttom edge to move. how can i adjust this code to achieve that?

```
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () in
     self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 5)
     })
    self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should need the order of the method calls your code (not absolutly necessary, but looks better):

```
self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () in
    self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 5)
})
```

This scale transform will shrink the view to the center; if you want to keep the top position, you would add a translateBy(x:y:) transformation and add it to the scale transform, more or less like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () in
    self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 5)
    let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,y: -100)
    let combined = scaleTransform.concatenating(translateTransform)
    self.topView.transform = combined 
})
```

Or you could just animate the frame of the view, as described here:
[Core Animation for UIView.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728434/core-animation-for-uiview-frame)

Comment: Thanks, it works (still need to adjust the details). Combining the transformation is something I did not know of